# Running function in Jquery .When().Done

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

The code below runs the alert("Success"); when it is alone and the function fSuccess is commented out, but it won't fire the fSuccess() function. Why is that? Thank you so much for your time.

```
$.when(chkUsername(), chkPassword()).done(function () {
                if (boolusername == 0) {
                    $("#ErrorUN").css("display", "block");
                }
                else {
                    if (boolpassword == 0) {
                        $("#ErrorP").css("display", "block");
                    }
                    else {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "Registration.aspx/Success",
                            data: "{}",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function () { }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }); //when





Imports System.Web.Services

Public Class Registration
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
End Sub

<WebMethod()>
Public Shared Sub Success()

   Dim strBreakPoint As String = "qwerty"

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: I made a few changes to the server side code, adding the reference to System.Web.Services and <WebMethod> , I also changed it to a Shared and now it works. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are declaring the function `fSuccess`, but never actually call it.

Besides that, you probably want to use the ajax callback, like this:

```
...
else {
    alert("Success!");
    //Add Server Side Function Here
    .ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Registration.aspx/Success",
        success: function() { alert("Success from server"); }
    });
}
...
```

Comment: I changed it and the alert fires, but not the server side code.

Answer (score 0):

You are simply declaring the function in that scope. You need to invoke it after it is defined.

```
fSuccess();
```